# cross browser extension with filtering

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to rewrite a firefox extension to a chrome extension. I used web extension [polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) but I don't know how to change the following codes:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener (function (details) {
   var filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
   filter.ondata = event => {
         req['response']['body'] = req['response']['body'] + decoder.decode(event.data);
         if (filter.status != "uninitialized" && event.data && event.data.byteLength > 0) {
            filter.write(event.data);
         }
      }
}
```

in another word, what can I use instead of "filterResponseData" in the chromium engine extensions?

Comment: There's no such thing in Chrome so it won't work.

Comment: so do you have any idea how can I change this code?  @wOxxOm

Comment: Generally it's not possible but depending on what exactly you change you may get lucky.